# How to replace the creditCard option with nonce using Braintree?

Tags: braintree

I have an application where I integrated braintree payment gateway. i am using custom form and not drop-in UI, i used creditCard parameter to do one time transaction from the clients credit card. I recently found that the creditCard parameter has been deprecated and a new parameter `paymentMethodNonce` has been introduced my previous code was

```
Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxxxxx');
Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxxxxx');
Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxxx');

$result = Braintree_Transaction::sale(array(
            'amount' => $price,
            'creditCard' => array(
                'number' => $card_number,
                'cardholderName' => $card_name,
                'expirationDate' => $expirationDate,
                'cvv' => $cvv
            )
));
```

According to the documentation I need to send a token within the form using a hidden input field to carry on the transaction, i added the token inside my form in the following way

```
<input type="hidden" name="payment_method_nonce" id="payment_method_nonce" value="<?=Braintree_ClientToken::generate()?>" />
```

and on the other page where i submit the form i changed the code to the following using the documentation bt still i receive validation error that

> Payment method token is invalid.

```
$payment_method_nonce   =   $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];
$result  = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '25.00',
    'paymentMethodToken' => $payment_method_nonce,
    'options' => [
      'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
  ]);
```

***Edited***

Here is the updated code

index.php

```
 <?php
    include 'db.php';
    include 'functions.php';
    require_once 'braintree-php-3.13.0/lib/Braintree.php';
    Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
    Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxxxxx');
    Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxxxxxx');
    Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxxxxx');
    $payment_method_nonce=  Braintree_ClientToken::generate();
?>
<script type="text/javascript" src="../../public_html/js/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="//code.jquery.com/ui/1.11.4/jquery-ui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.creditCardValidator.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="js/card.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="style.css">


<style>
    label, input { display:block; }
    input.text { margin-bottom:12px; width:95%; padding: .4em; }
    fieldset { padding:0; border:0; margin-top:25px; }
    h1 { font-size: 1.2em; margin: .6em 0; }
    div#users-contain { width: 350px; margin: 20px 0; }
    div#users-contain table { margin: 1em 0; border-collapse: collapse; width: 100%; }
    div#users-contain table td, div#users-contain table th { border: 1px solid #eee; padding: .6em 10px; text-align: left; }
    .ui-dialog .ui-state-error { padding: .3em; }
    .validateTips { border: 1px solid transparent; padding: 0.3em; }
</style>


<script type="text/javascript">
    //    braintree dialouge
    var form;
    $(document).ready(function () {
        dialog = $("#dialog-form").dialog({
            autoOpen: false,
            height: 500,
            width: 500,
            modal: true,
            close: function () {
                form[0].reset();
            }
        });

//        form = dialog.find("form").on("submit", function (event) {
//            event.preventDefault();
//        });

        $("#create-user").button().on("click", function () {
            dialog.dialog("open");
        });
        console.log("Here");



    });

</script>

<button name="create-user" id="create-user">Open Dialouge</button>
<div id="dialog-form" style="display:none;">
    <form method="post"  id="paymentForm" action="cardprocess.php">

        <ul>
            <li>
                <label>Card Number </label>
                <input type="text" name="card_number" id="card_number"  maxlength="20" placeholder="1234 5678 9012 3456"/>
            </li>
<!--            <li>
                <label>Name on Card</label>
                <input type="text" name="card_name" id="card_name" placeholder="Card Holder Name"/>
            </li>-->
            <li class="vertical">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <label>Expires</label>
                        <input type="text" name="expiry_month" id="expiry_month" maxlength="2" placeholder="MM" class="inputLeft" />
                        <input type="text" name="expiry_year" id="expiry_year" maxlength="2" placeholder="YY" class="inputLeft" />
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <label>CVV</label>
                        <input type="text" name="cvv" id="cvv" maxlength="3" placeholder="123" class="inputLeft" />
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </li>
            <li>
                <input type="submit" id="paymentButton" value="Proceed" disabled="true" class="disable">
            </li>
        </ul>
    </form>
</div>
<div id="orderInfo"></div>
<script src="https://js.braintreegateway.com/js/braintree-2.26.0.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
     braintree.setup('<?=$payment_method_nonce?>', 'custom', {
            id: "paymentForm",
            hostedFields: {
                number: {
                  selector: "#card_number"
                },
                expirationMonth: {
                  selector: "#expiry_month"
                },
                expirationYear: {
                  selector: "#expiry_year"
                },
                cvv: {
                  selector: "#cvv"
                },
          },
          onError:function (errorObj){
              console.log(errorObj.type);
              console.log(errorObj.message);
          }
        });
</script>
```

cardprocess.php

```
    <?php

    include 'db.php';
    include 'functions.php';       

    $price = '1000';
require_once 'braintree-php-3.13.0/lib/Braintree.php';
        Braintree_Configuration::environment('sandbox');
        Braintree_Configuration::merchantId('xxxx');
        Braintree_Configuration::publicKey('xxxx');
        Braintree_Configuration::privateKey('xxxxxxx');
    if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

        $payment_method_nonce   =   $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];




        $result  = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
            'amount' => '25.00',
            'paymentMethodNonce' => $payment_method_nonce,
            'options' => [
              'submitForSettlement' => True
            ]
          ]);

        if ($result->success) {
            if ($result->transaction->id) {
                $braintreeCode = $result->transaction->id;
                echo "<pre>";
                print_r($braintreeCode);
                //updateUserOrder($braintreeCode, $session_user_id);
            }
        } else if ($result->transaction) {
            echo '{"OrderStatus": [{"status":"2"}]}';
        } else {
            print_r($result);
            echo '{"OrderStatus": [{"status":"0"}]}';
        }
    }
    ?>
```

```

Comment: can you explain why was it downvoted or you just liked to downvote it ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

<sub>Full disclosure: I work at Braintree. If you have any further questions, feel free to contact [support](https://support.braintreepayments.com/).</sub>

The Braintree client token and the payment method nonce are two distinct elements. The client token should be generated on your server and used to [configure the JavaScript SDK](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/client-side/javascript/v2#create-a-form) with the token and the DOM ID of your HTML form; after that, you don’t need to worry about adding and populating the hidden field yourself. On submission of the form, Braintree creates a payment method nonce and sends it with the form through a hidden input.

On the server side, your code also needs a slight adjustment: you’re currently sending a `paymentMethodToken`, which refers to the unique identifier of an existing payment method. The key for the nonce should instead be `paymentMethodNonce`, as outlined in the [credit card guide](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/credit-cards/server-side/php#creating-transactions).

```
$payment_method_nonce = $_POST['payment_method_nonce'];
$result  = Braintree_Transaction::sale([
    'amount' => '25.00',
    'paymentMethodNonce’ => $payment_method_nonce,
    'options' => [
      'submitForSettlement' => True
    ]
 ]);
```

Comment: hmm that was a stupid mistake by me, you are right about it i had to revise the code here is the complete code that i updated, i am using the hosted fields after updating the code i am getting a `js error` of `type validation` with message `User did not enter a payment method`, when i tried to investigate i found that the hidden input is not populating inside my form after calling the `braintree.setup()` , see above i edited the post and added the full code under the Edited Section including the form and server side processing.

Comment: As noted in the Hosted Fields [integration example](https://developers.braintreepayments.com/guides/hosted-fields/setup-and-integration/javascript/v2#basic-integration), "You will need to define `<div>` containers in place of the `<input>` elements that would normally comprise your credit card input fields (card number, expiration date, and CVV)." It looks like your form currently uses `<input>` elements.

If this doesn't solve your issue, I'd suggest reaching out to [Braintree support](https://support.braintreepayments.com).

Comment: Yes you are right about providing the div containers rather than the input elements , that was the problem, thanks alot for replying